How to Organise/Present Built Worlds?
Suppose one has mostly completed a worldbuilding project, and made a setting detailed enough for its purpose (e.g. running a TTRPG campaign in one). How should the available information be presented/ordered, especially when using a book-like medium (whether a dead tree book, a PDF, or something similar).
My main concern is the competing purposes of such a book being introductory on a first read (thus benefitting from keeping the specific articles short, and only presenting in-depth articles on a given topic in some later part of the book, after the reader has familiarised herself with all the basics) and being a reference for repeat uses (thus benefitting from having all the material on a given topic gathered in one place, e.g. all the technological development being in one chapter, all the geopolitical reference data being in one other chapter, all the theology being in yet another chapter).
How is a product of worldbuilding coherently presented/published to minimise the problems such as these and optimise ability to convey an understanding of a world?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Write lots of short articles, not a compendium
Because this is a TTRPG, most characters will not have a full knowledge of the World's history, politics, etc.  I remember running a campaign years ago, where I created dozens of articles about the history, law, and customs of the setting, designed numerous maps depicting towns, regions, and the whole world, and created home-brew rules about many common types of monsters to make sure that they could still feel new, even to experienced players.
The thing that every player got at the beginning of the campaign was maybe a 1 page summary of the world they were in... which was okay because they had no special training or experience with any of that, but everyone who took certain skill points at character creation would receive extra articles, maps, monster sheets, etc. about the world.
This way, players with low lore-related stats were mostly in the dark about what to expect, and players with higher lore-related stats could often just know things their character should know so that they could call things out without even having to roll for it, and when they did have to roll for stuff, I could just give them the article.
I think most DMs would consider it more work than it was worth, but it did make the world feel like it was revealing itself in a more natural way by compromising what a person who lives in a world should know with learning about it as you explore it.  Also, many players may not want to read much about a world before they start; so, those guys got to just get the cliff notes and go.

Two books

My main concern is the competing purposes[...] being introductory
[...] and being a reference for repeat uses.

Instead of trying to have a book with two very opposite goals you could just write two books that each serve their purpose.
Write a short book that is meant as introduction, showing all relevant aspects of your world on low depth level.
Then write a second longer book, which serves as an encyclopedia with indepth articles on all the topics. Or depending on how deep your world building is you could even write multiple encyclopedias about one topic each.
I'd even advice you to write the encyclopedia first so that you can reference it from the introductory work. Like "For more on this topic refer to ENC page 397." As a foot note after a chapter about the theology.
Though keep in mind that you now have to "cross proof read" both books to make sure that the two sources don't contradict each other.
Especially the encyclopedia could benefit from wiki-esque cross links between articles that would be enabled in a digital version.
For the introductory work also consider packing part of the information in short (max 1 page long) stories to make them more accessible. Only few like to read a 50 page long info dump that scratches the surface of all topics.
Source: I read a lot of rule and fluff books for various TTRPGs and when these techniques were used it was the most accessible for me and my friends.

Note that reference by page to another book is very hard to keep in sync while editing said other book. Instead, it can be useful to reference by "path" (§4.3.2) or by shortname ([basic.lifetime]) as used in ISO documents. Hopefully, those can then be indexed within the book automatically, either in a ToS at the beginning, or an index at the end.

You can also format the page headings on each book to include the section number or name, providing most of the access convenience of page-number references without tying the reference to physical pages.

Write it in sections with different levels of detail.

The first section would have the tourist blurb.

The next part would be what people outside that would know about it
as common knowledge.

The next part would be what the locals know as common knowledge.

The last could be a series of in depth articles about it.


The fun part is that some of the earlier sections can be contradicted in the later sections.

The Chorography

A work of utility.  A chorography is a systematic description and mapping of a place. Whether that place is Britain or the Earth or some other planet, this type of book condenses a whole library of information into one convenient volume. In and of itself, it is the introductory work while at the same time also the more in depth look at the world you're describing. Typically, a chorography will handle a treatise on the natural history of the world, describing the universe and the planet's place within it as well as the geology, topography, geography and related topics.


This sort of work begins with the big topics: the metaphysics of the universe, creation, what happened before time began and all. Here, you would lay out the fundamental nature of the universe as understood from those living within it.

Here also, the topics like celestial mechanics, the physical properties of the universe, the various kinds of celestial objects one might find are introduced. Here too, we begin to move towards the smaller scale. The local neighbourhood of the galaxy a/o solar system become introduced as well as the various chronological cycles.

The focus then shifts to the world in question. Here we delve into matters of geology, geography, natural history and planetary history. So here we'll see what kind of planet this is, what its history is, what lives in and on this planet and what kinds of peoples we'll find there.

We can then narrow the focus a bit more to those aspects of the world we at least think are more important: the people. We'll find descriptions of the various races of the world, whether they are corporeal or aetherial or something else; we'll discover some of the broad trends of history, the ages of the world and the great sagas that tell of those various times.


With the broad strokes of introduction now laid down, we move on to the more detailed work. In a sense, we'll begin again, but at a smaller order of magnitude. We'll divide the next part of the book up into the great land areas: continents, islands, empires, regions, etc. If you're writing from an in-world perspective, you might begin with the area you focus on as a writer, or the region where the author of the book lives.

Here, we'll describe the geography of the region in broad terms and then delve into the various countries of that region. A couple of avenues present themselves to us.

For each country, we could follow a predetermined scheme, such as "Country A: races, cultures, religions, politics, economics, daily life, curious anecdotes // Country B: races, cultures, religions, politics, economics, daily life, curious anecdotes // etc".
Alternatively, if numerous countries share some basics of history, language, culture or religion, we could say: "Country D: Sharing the same gods as Countries A, B & C, we might here take notice of a peculiar set of festivals and sacrifices that have been organised together in a way not seen in the other countries..."
In addition to the treatment of the various countries, we can also bring out certain curiosities of philosophy or folklore or history or culture to break up the iterative nature of this part of the work. For example, after we've read four or five countries worth of races, cultures, religions, etc. we might just come across a sort of random aside on a particular game that people play. This could be a much more detailed exposition, perhaps noting differences of play in different countries. This could also lead to a short treatise on games in general, their history and so forth that we might not otherwise see in a strictly geographical work.



Ultimately, the point of a chorography is not to reinvent the wheel, and it is not to replace a whole library. As regards our secondary worlds, I think it is fair to assume that most of them have disciplines like astronomy, like history, like theology, like mythology. A chorography doesn't have to begin each topic from first principles. Those can be assumed. It should focus on what is interesting and curious. We don't need to write an entire dissertation on zoology just to enumerate and describe the fauna of the world. Reference can be made of course, as that science would be assumed to exist.

And just as we began our journey into this world through its own creation, so too we might part from it at its ending. He we might consider the broad trends of natural and sophont history, we might consider that underlying metaphysics, we might even consider the time in universal history we're exploring this world in order to cast our imaginations forwards! We might dwell on questions of eschatology or endings and of meaning and why, exactly, it is that squirrels shall be the ultimate cause of doom.

And of course, no work of this sort can exist without maps, indices and a whole host of appendices! Here of course, we'll find the atlas, but also perhaps some appendices on languages, perhaps even some short texts in those languages, maybe some time lines, some interesting charts of odd things like comparing units of measure & money, key doctrinal distinctions between religions, curious statements of philosophy, etc.


A work of art.  A chorography, or any kind of presentation of an entire secondary world, ought to be more than merely a wall of text that imparts data. There are of course places for the mere impartation of data, but the world itself deserves a little better.

In as much as geopoesy is an art, that wherein a secondary world is created, so too the  chorography that describes its world should also be a work of art in and of itself. Whether the world is a high fantasy or a low sci-fi place, the presentation itself speaks to us about the world we're reading about.

As a work of art in and of itself, the chororography ought to be well written. Whether we have opted for an external or an internal perspective, we should ensure that the text itself flows thematically, that it's well written, is grammatical and is conveyed with characteristic style and flair. Let it be well planned out and formatted. Make good use of chapters and sections and headings. Use beautiful fonts. If appropriate and economical, make good use of colour!

The work itself should be something that attracts the reader, the beholder, the collector, the artistic interlocutor. Apart from me merely telling you about my world, I actually want to immerse you into it. As matters of presentation, wikis are fine, online encyclopedia type things are fine, a three ring binder full of data sheets is also fine. But they aren't terribly engaging. A chorography, when done with art, acts as a means to translate you to a different time, a different place. It is something that you can hold in your hands and say: yes, this is an artifact of that other world; when I read this, my eyes see what a person of that other world sees and I experience, if briefly, what that other person experiences.



Make Names that are directories and put a short snippet at the correct level of abstraction.
Like:
World_Land_Continent_Religions : Catholicism
World_Land_Continent_Country_City_Cathedral: Building of said religion
etc.
etc.
The name describes the location always from the global to the local. You can use links to link global concepts to a character.
Use that as a navigation concept for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zettelkasten.
Also do not be a purist about it. Sometimes information is clingy and should stay together. A magic system if global, is something that is the same on all worlds. And should stay global and not distributed multiple times within the system. Thats another big thing. Do not duplicate information. Everything is there- once. This is one of the reasons modern document management systems reinvented the iframe, to allow you to show excerpts of one page within another.

I suggest using files as directories in this case. Foo.txt is both a file and a folder that contains Foo.Bar.txt

The Fluff and the Crunch
I am going to liberally reference WH40K here, because I think it does a good job of doing this.
So - your reference material is typically going to be your Crunch, I do not know your game mechanics or the purpose of your world building, but generally things that need to be repeatedly referenced would be things like Stat sheets, Rules etc. etc.
However, so that this is not bland, you can intersperse this with little small anecdotes about your world, even the rules themselves can be part of your world building
For example:
Vengence of the slain ancestors
3 Generations ago, the brutal tribe of the northern warlords harried and pillaged the unguarded barbarian villages of the east. As the women, children and elders were cut down, they collectively cursed the Warlords and their descendents with a Curse.
When a Barbarian attacks a character from the Northern Warlords - they gain +2 strength.
From this, we know that there is a group in the north and a group in the east, we know that magic exists such to have a practical application, we know there is enmity between these two groups and we know that this is ongoing.
Depending on the formatting, you can also have fluff around it - so for WH40K, you might have a Stat table for a Champion character, then off to the side a short anecdote about that character:
"When Character was just out of training, they slew big enemy in single combat" - you get the idea.
This is essentially your Rule book - you can spice it up with an introduction and add as much surrounding fluff to it as you like, whilst still keeping the key info (e.g. the reference bits) easily accessible.
The Fluff
This should be lots of short, compelling stories that introduce elements of your world to the reader.
If it absolutely must be one book, you can break up sections of the Crunch with sections of Fluff, so long as it is easily accessible e.g. for each section, a short intro of Fluff, then the stat sheets (like above) then at the end of it, some more fluffy lore.

Your mileage may vary but I find a selection of sorted bullet points is the best way to store my world builds, but that is for me as a GM or author that doesn't go very far towards making the material accessible to an audience which is where you're at. I'm not sure this is really something we should be speaking to, it is after all very much a matter of opinion, it sounds more like a discussion for the Roleplaying stack chat under a "who do you think presents their setting best" banner. Having said that I have an opinion and the community seems to think I should share:
With TTRPG in particular in mind I have always been a huge fan of Jackpoint, the discussion forum style of fluff/lore presentation in Shadowrun, I find it a deeply immersive technique that really pulls me into the world of the characters and keeps me there. I want to see the world from the POV of those who live there, preferably people like my character, or who my character aspires to be.
I like small blocks of information presented in a logical order, alphabetical and timeline orders are traditional but I've also seen a geographical order used quite successfully working north to south and west to east down the world map.
Information should be split up along useful categorical lines to keep lists short and on point. I've played in several prewritten adventures in particular where information, particularly statistical character data, is presented in blocks that don't match the order of presentation needed for the story. I've read databomb first chapters that I had to return to continuously throughout what could have been an immersive narrative. Neither is useful.
The net result of these preferences is that I would personally like to see a setting primer, probably involving things like the historical timeline, map(s), current affairs etc... written with a first person narrative and/or with commentary from a "man on the street" perspective. This to be followed by chapters on specific areas of particular interest, and/or events that bear further attention in the same style. This being where the lore is all hung out to be seen. Finally a very cut and dried section purely composed of technical data sheets giving all the statistical data that goes with the lore/story/world elements that have gone before, this means if I need to check a price/weight/height/wording of effect, I can flip to the back of the book and find it without wading through fluff.

IMHO, Most TTRPG since the 1970s have either taken some inspiration from the blueprint put forward by D&D or reacted against it.   :
Resource for the Player (e.g. Player's Handbook):   All the mechanics of character creation with descriptions of possible choices such as races, classes, skills, abilities, spells.  Appendices might also include a system for progression like  Level tables, and possibly equipment and weapon costs and descriptions.
Resource for the Game Manager (e.g. Dungeon Master's Guide):  Rules for running a game including managing combat and skill checks,  advice and inspiration for campaign creators, high level world lore, tables for generating random encounters and settings,  descriptions of loot.
Resources detailing the Inhabitants of your World (e.g. Monster Manual): Stats and descriptions for all the creatures and races in your world the players will encounter. (A bestiary.)
Additional Resources for New Settings (e.g. Modules): Detailed maps and descriptions of specific regions, with adventures and campaigns.
When I think about it, A TTRPG requires some form of all these elements or components.

As it happens, I've done a lot of worldbuilding myself for the purposes of making my own TTRPG settings.
In most cases, my worldbuilding has been with and for a group of players who have been involved in my worldbuilding.  As they know almost as much about my worlds as I do, that influences the presentation of the setting's writeup.
Where the consumer of a built world is at least moderately familiar with the world, one need only explain new material, and present the nitty-gritty details of existing features in a sort of encyclopedia.  Being familiar with the basics of the world, the reader knows that, for example, in my Airworld setting, Topos Symvoliou was a constructed island built for international diplomacy, that was destroyed long ago.  However, they might not remember that The Heralds were founded to administer Topos Symvoliou for the participating nations' delegates, or the particular date upon which the island was destroyed.
The problem with an encyclopedia is that when a new player comes along who is completely unfamiliar with the setting, it is a very dull and dry way of introducing the setting.  Unless the player enjoys reading as much as I do, they probably won't want to wade into reading the encyclopedia from cover to cover.
This leads us to introductory blurbs.  This is a technique used a great deal for the Glorantha setting, which is a TTRPG setting that has multiple editions of rules and a vast mass of lore dating back to its creation in 1966... including a multi-volume encyclopedia.  However, for new players, there are introductory blurbs that have been written for the benefit of new players who are going to be playing members of one of the many distinct cultures of Glorantha.  These blurbs give a few pertinent details about what the average person in that culture knows... how they live, who their culture's friends and enemies are, what their culture's people value and fear, how their magic works... all distilled down to a few pages of information that most people could digest relatively easily without requiring a week of reading and studying as if for an exam.
Once a player has an 'in' to the world, they will hopefully have motivation to go looking for more information when the bare-bones information they are initially presented with falls short.
This differs from the process of worldbuilding for a story (which I have also done).  In a story, the writer must feed the reader with pieces of the world, a bit at a time, hopefully not so quickly that the reader can't absorb the details that they've read and end up getting lost.
